# How to execute cron job properly with magento - exception Mage_Core_Exception with message Invalid model/method definition

Tags: php, magento, exception, cron, magento-1.9

I will go straight to the point as much as I can, I am using Magento 1.9.
I have the following piece of code in my simple cron module and each time the cron job is performed I could see the schedule is logged fine but I see the following errors in the log on the message.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid model/method
>   definition, expecting "model/class::method".' in /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/Mage.php:595
>
> Stack trace: #0 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(299):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid model/m...')
>
> #1 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72):
>   Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>
> #2 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358):
>   Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> #3 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> #4 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/app/Mage.php(448):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
>
> #5 /Users/XXXXX/Sites/projects/php/web/magento/magento_test1.9/SRC/test_cron.php(76):
>   Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
>
> #6 {main}

My config:
config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!-- lets define the module name and version -->
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Update>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mymodule_Update>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
            <!-- lets define the module router i.e. for request to any controller within the module and action e.g. mymodule/controller/action -->
        <routers>
            <update>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mymodule_Update</module>
                    <frontName>mymoduleupdate</frontName>
                </args>
            </update>
        </routers>
        <!-- lets define the layout to be used by this module -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <update module="Mymodule_Update">
                    <file>mymoduleupdate.xml</file>
                </update>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <!-- every 5 minute-->
            <mymodule_update_in>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * * </cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>
                        mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateIn
                    </model>
                </run>
            </mymodule_update_in>
            <!-- every 5 minute-->
            <mymodule_update_out>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * * </cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>
                        mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateOut
                    </model>
                </run>
            </mymodule_update_out>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
    <global>

            <!-- lets define the models to use-->
        <models>
            <mymodule_update>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_update_resource</resourceModel>
                <class>Mymodule_Update_Model</class>
            </mymodule_update>
            <mymodule_update_resource>
                <class>Mymodule_Update_Model_Resource</class>
            </mymodule_update_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule_update>
                <class>Mymodule_Update_Helper</class>
            </mymodule_update>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_update_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mymodule_Update</module>
                    <class>Mymodule_Update_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mymodule_update_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>

        </events>
    </global>

</config>
```

My class
Updater.php:

```
<?php 
class Mymodule_Update_Model_updater
{
    public function performUpdateIn()
    {
        die("hello in");
    }


    public function performUpdateOut()
    {
        die("hello out");
    }
}
?>
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried using the

```
mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateOut
update/updater::performUpdateOut
```

or

```
mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateIn
update/updater::performUpdateIn
```

same error is what i get. I will like anyone whose got an idea why this is going wrong to point me to the right direction thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem is spacing between the xml tags for the action to perform

i.e.

```
                <model>
                    mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateOut
                </model>
```

Should be

```
<model>mymodule_update/updater::performUpdateOut</model>
```

likewise for the performUpdateIn.

Trying to beautify or allow some code editors to add spaces in between could result into hours of unnecessary mental labor.